# Printf waiting for enter

Tags: c, printf, getchar

```
int kr=0;
int ss =0;
while ((kr=getchar()) != EOF){
      if(kr != '\n')
      {
        ss++;
      }

      printf("%d\n",ss);
}
```

With this code , printf is waiting until i press enter then printing all the sequential ss values at the same time like in this

[image]

.  Can somebody explain this behavior ?

Comment: printf has nothing to do with waiting behaviour... it is getchar(). but first try to clean your project and rebuild it...And try again.

Comment: is there a way to disable the input buffer stream for getchar() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf` is not waiting it is `getchar` instead. `getchar` uses a buffer behind the scene. When that buffer is empty, `getchar` will read 1 line from stdin and **then** return the first caracter. If it is not empty, it will return the next caracter from the buffer immediatly.

That means that the `getchar` will wait the first time you call it. And thus your `printf` is never executed until you press `enter`

Comment: what does this have to do with me being have to press enter everytime i want something printed. I dont understand your explanation

Comment: @DogusUral It means that the `getchar` in the condition of your loop is blocking until you press enter, the `printf` is never executed until you press enter.